# How to get results from other website

Tags: php, curl

I need to fetch data from this web page [Sender score](http://senderscore.org)
.I try to use cURL but it renders white page.

Here is my code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
$keyword = "an-example.com";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.senderscore.org/lookup.php?lookup='.$keyword.'&validLookup=true');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($data);
curl_close($ch);
```

any idea ?

Regards.

Comment: Try turning on error reporting and display errors, what error messages do you get? Just the code isn't really enough for us to help with the issue.
`error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Have you installed cURL in your system?

Comment: Turning on error reporting and display errors would show a message if the `curl_init`, `curl_setopt`, `curl_exec`, or `curl_close` functions are not available which is why I suggested that. That is most likely the cause.

Comment: SenderScore has a captcha specifically to block automated lookups like this.

Comment: senderscore.org does not allow what you are trying to achieve....

Comment: @RaviHirani yes I checked curl in php extensions.

Comment: This doesn't negate the fact that there could still be errors. If there are indeed no errors, then yes, your issue is the captcha. Take the proper steps to debug your issues.

Comment: @JustinE there is no error in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a blank page because of the captcha which is needed to fill in. Perhaps senderscore has an API which you can use? Or maybe there's another website available doing the same thing. I thought this was about scoring email statusus right? Then maybe this site will help you out: http://www.reputationauthority.org/domain_lookup.php?ip=somedomain.nl&Submit.x=0&Submit.y=0&Submit=Search

I can use this site without the need of captcha or any other bot interference.

Comment: Return transfer should be returning the raw HTML, not a blank page.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want to do @Baklap4 I'll try this website and I keep you in touch. Thanx

Comment: One thing about reputationauthority it gives me my website in its grid, I suppose it should returns the set of IP addresses availables right ?

Comment: the latter would be the best yeah. Try to find something which has a documented api which returns json or something you can use instead of raw html. such a site can be: http://mxtoolbox.com/api/v1/lookup/dns/example.com

Comment: Curl returns the raw html from the query.  If you want the IP Addresses, you will need to parse the HTML or use an API.

Comment: if this helped you out please assign the answer

Comment: Thank you @JustinE for your answer, but I have to make a step before looking to parse my html.

Comment: @Baklap4 I used mxtoolbox to generate IPs and I compare them with the ones generated by sender score, I can see that they generate different IPs, is that normal ?

Comment: @zackzulg depends if the domain has a cluster of servers running below it (multiple ip's) or a single server (1 ip). In case of a cluster one would mostly get the server which is the nearest

Comment: Thank you @Baklap4 for you suggestions.

Comment: @JustinE you say I have to parse my response. I tried json to retrieve only td with special class, but it doesn't work.